# Returning Data from an Asynchronous Command in a WPF MVVM Application

Tags: wpf, mvvm, asynchronous

I’m having a bit of difficulty getting this to work – and to be honest, I feel I may not be even doing this with the right approach.

In my View I have a Button and two list boxes.

What I want is to click the button and have the two list boxes populate with two separate lists of strings in an Asynchronous fashion.

In my ViewModel, I have two ObservableCollection properties and these are what the ListBox.ItemsSource properties are bound too. All good.

Now, I have an instance of AsyncDelegateCommand (outlined in this post - http://www.amazedsaint.com/2010/10/asynchronous-delegate-command-for-your.html#) which I have data bound to the Command property of the button.

In the DoSomething() method, I have just made a quick sample that constructs a list of random strings with a few sleep in-between to simulate some elapsed time.

How can I return this collection for use in the ViewModel? and then to take it a step further, How can I return multiple instances of this collection for multiple ListBoxes?

I hope this makes sense!

Kris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `AsyncDelegateCommand` you referenced, you would subscribe to the Command's `Completed` event, and add the results of your collection from event args `Result` to your ObservableCollection.

This will automatically happen in the correct synchronization context (since that command uses BackgroundWorker to function), which will allow your UI to update appropriately.

Comment: Thanks! totally missed that :)